# Asp.net Core 2 - Static files not working on prod but they work through iis express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When  running my asp.net core 2  app (web api) locally on iis express, calling static resources seem to work, but when deployed to iis 8 i get a 404 trying to access.
Here is my setup, locally i put the resource in wwwroot while startup.cs, program.cs are one directory higher.

when deployed, all the compiled/published dlls and the resource are deployed to the wwwroot of website.  Now my apis work fine onlie, for example i have a route defined such as

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/misc/categories")]
 public IActionResult Categories()
 {
     return Ok(DbContext.Categories);
 }
```

so calling http://cryptocal.imetasoft.com/api/misc/categories returns the categories as it should but http://cryptocal.imetasoft.com/index.html returns a 404, even though the index.html and cryptocal.dll are both in the wwwroot on my webserver (prod)

I believe I have everything setup properly.
I added a nuget package to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles v2.0`

**.csproj content**

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="morelinq" Version="2.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Program.cs** No changes (defaults from generated template)

using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

```
namespace CryptoCal
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using CryptoCal.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CryptoCal.Support;

namespace CryptoCal
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CryptoDateContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CryptoCalDatabase")));
            services.Configure<GeneralSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("GeneralSettings"));
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(x =>
            {

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect the DLL files and your static files to be in the same folder, if you meant that the way you stated it. When properly deployed the DLLs are likely in the root and the static files are in the subfolder wwwroot. Perhaps that's what you meant?

Comment: when creating sites in websitepanel, the root that it puts for iis's Physical Path is set to the wwwroot (I guess that's just how this thing does it).  So in reality my "root" of my site is a folder called wwwroot and inside that I will have another wwwroot for core. This is my first core deployment and before that everything, dlls, bin, etc were dumped into wwwroot.

Comment: I'm not sure what "websitepanel" is; that may be a relevant edit to make to your question.

Comment: really should be irrelevant because
iis points: C:\HostingSpaces\admin\cryptocal.imetasoft.com\wwwroot and inside that folder at root i have the dlls and then another folder called wwwroot for the static files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was an oversight on my part, the content of wwwroot should be higher than where the dlls go, I am not sure why I was putting them in the same folder in the first place. @k3davis was correct in the first place

IIS pointing to \

\dlls
\wwwroot for all static files